# Rails: Updating an object from within a callback of an associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a “parent class” called Exam and that has many instances of a Score class. I want to modify an attribute on the Exam instance when one of the associated scores is saved. I stripped all the classes down to this very simple example, which looks stupid, but illustrates the problem in its most basic form. Here are the classes.

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores

  def score_saved
    # self.name is now "Software Engineering"
    self.name = "#{name}!"
    # self.name is now "Software Engineering!"
  end
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam
  belongs_to :course

  before_save :trigger_score_saved

  def trigger_score_saved
    exam.score_saved unless exam.nil?
  end
end
```

Then I run the following test:

```
class ExamTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "create new exam" do
    exam = Exam.new(:name => "Software Engineering 1")
    score = exam.scores.build(:grade => 80, :course => courses(:one))
    exam.save

    # self.name is still "Software Engineering" here
    assert_equal "Software Engineering 1!", exam.name 
  end 
end
```

The comments in the code already illustrate the problem: the update of the name attribute of the exam object does not take place. Mind you, the trigger_score_saved proc is executed, but the newly set value is not the one that’s eventually saved to the database.
If I define a `before_save :trigger_score_saved` callback on the exam object itself, the name attribute *does* get updated correctly. So it seems to have something to do with the fact that there’s a cascading save going on and that maybe the parent exam object on which the save started is different from the score.exam object that I’m trying to modify the value of.

Can anyone explain what’s going on here and how I can successfully update a parent object’s attribute from within the callback of a “child object”?

Notes:

- I use Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2
- I’ve tried `update_attribute(:name => "#{name}!")` instead of `self.name = "#{name}!"`, but both have the same effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some more investigating and as it turns out, my problem is actually very simply solved by specifying the `:inverse_of` attribute on the relevant associations:

```
class Exam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores, :inverse_of => :exam
  ...
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exam, :inverse_of => :scores
  ...
end
```

This way `exam.scores.first.exam` *is* the exact same instance as `exam`, since the `:inverse_of` attribute tells Rails to use the same object instance in memory!

Additionally, I want the exam to be updated on any CRUD action on any score, so also when I delete a score from the exam.scores collection. This is where association callbacks like `:after_remove` come in handy.

So all with these tools up my belt, it seems that I can move forward even without an Identity Map (even though, I definitely do see the value in having one of those in Rails).

Comment: Sadly inverse_of doesn't work with polymorphic associations, which requires calling `score.reload` for the updates to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

As you surmised, there are different instances of the Exam class in memory that reference the same DB row. You could call #reload to refresh, or wait for the identity work to make it in a released Rails version.

Some references to the identity map:

- [ActiveRecord::ObjectMap - Identity Map for AR](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3099-activerecordobjectmap-identity-map-for-ar)
- [ActiveRecord Identity Map Ruby Summer of Code](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-core/browse_thread/thread/73b2a9e1aacda9a7)
- [DataMapper Why - Identity Map](http://datamapper.org/why#identity_map)

Comment: Thanks so much, François! This was exactly the insight I was looking for! Would you also be able to tell me what would be the correct way to handle this problem of updating the parent object when one of the children is saved?

Comment: You are already using the "correct" way. ActiveRecord as it stands today does not have a way to grab the instance you're looking for. You have to reload and play it safe. I often call #reload in my tests, looking for the freshest values. This often happens in controller tests, where the instance I used to setup the DB is different than the one the controller will use, since the controller will call ActiveRecord::Base#find anew, and get a newly instantiated instance.